# How do I get a reference to ConnectivityService object?

Tags: android

I've tried everything I can think of. I tried to call getInstance(), but the class wasn't in my SDK.

```
ConnectivityService cs = ConnectivityService.getInstance(this);
```

I tried using reflection to do the above,

```
Class csClass = Class.forName("com.android.server.ConnectivityService");
Method getInstanceMethod = csClass.getDeclaredMethod("getInstance", Context.class);
Object cs = getInstanceMethod.invoke(null, this); // this = Context
```

but it gave a security exception saying I needed WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permissions, but those permissions are only available to manufacturers.

I tried to get it via ServiceManager, but it only returned an android.os.BinderProxy class.

```
IBinder cs = ServiceManager.getService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
Log.d("HelloWorld", "cs.class:"+cs.getClass());
```

Finally, I tried to access the static field in ConnectivityService which holds an instance of itself, but it was null.

```
Class csClass = Class.forName("com.android.server.ConnectivityService");
for (Field f : csClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
    f.setAccessible(true);
    if (Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers())) {
        Log.d("HelloWorld", "ConnectivityServiceExt."+f.getName() + ": " + f.get(null));
    }
}
Field sServiceInstanceField = csClass.getDeclaredField("sServiceInstance");
sServiceInstanceField.setAccessible(true); // private
Object cs = sServiceInstanceField.get(null); // ConnectivityService object
```

I even tried to access ConnectivityServiceExt.sServiceInstance, but that was also null too.

Once I get a hold of it, I want to try additional calls on ConnectivityService using reflection to turn the radios on.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do with ConnectivityService?

Comment: Turn on the 3G radio manually.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a little stale, but for posterity:

I think you really want the IConnectivityManager. The ordinary ConnectivityManger will not do.

```
Class<?> serviceManagerClass = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager");
Method getServiceMethod = serviceManagerClass.getMethod("getService", new Class[]{String.class});
IBinder serviceManager = (IBinder)getServiceMethod.invoke(null, new Object[]{Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE});

// Now use pass the ServiceManager BinderProxy to the 'asInterface' method of the interface Stub inner class
Class<?> stubClass = Class.forName("android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub");
Method asInterfaceMethod = stubClass.getMethod("asInterface", new Class[]{IBinder.class});
Object IConnectivityManager = asInterfaceMethod.invoke(null, serviceManager);

// Now call the 'setRadios' method to turn on radios
Class<?> IConnectivityManagerClass = IConnectInterface.getClass();  
Method setRadiosMethod = IConnectivityManagerClass.getMethod("setRadios",Boolean.TYPE);
Object retVal = setRadiosMethod.invoke(IConnectivityManager,new Boolean[] {new Boolean(true)});
```

You will probably also need to get permission android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE

Answer (score 0):

Once I used ConnectivityService in the following way:

```
ConnectivityManager mgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Comment: That gets a ConnectivityManager object, not a ConnectivityService object. They have different methods if you look at the Android source code.