# How could I configure system proxy with my app in Android?

Tags: android, proxy, root

I often use `Fiddler4` to capture data that comes from an Android phone.

Every time I have to go to `system settings - WiFi - advanced options` and set the proxy to 192.168.1.xxx:8888. Then I have to close it when I finished my work.

Now I want to make a simple app which only has a togglebutton to finish the tedious configuration job. Where could I start from?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have access to a ConnectivityService object ([this should help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16618286/108984)), create a new [ProxyInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ProxyInfo.html) object and use it as a parameter to the setGlobalProxy() method of the ConnectivityService object.